Avoid infinite loop when using a JavaScript for loop to iterate over an array and call gtag events
I am working on tracking user engagement with an ecommerce store. One of the features is adding a shopping list of items to your cart. This event has a datalayer instance which gets overwritten when the page reload and populates the basket. Before that happens I am saving the datalayer to session storage. Then on page load, for each item added to the basket I want to log an add to cart event within Google Analytics 4. I intend to do this via a custom gtag event, but when this runs it goes into an infinite loop.
Example code below
var newCartItems = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cartContents"));
var keyLength = Object.keys(newCartItems).length -1;
var myCustomCartProducts = newCartItems[keyLength].ecommerce.add.products;
 
for(i = 0 ; i < myCustomCartProducts.length; i++) {  
 
 gtag(
                "event", "add_to_cart_multi", {
                "value": myCustomCartProducts[i].price * myCustomCartProducts[i].quantity,
                "currency": "{{Ga4 dlv ecommerce.currencyCode}}",
                "page_type": "{{CJS - Page Type}}",
                "search_term": "{{1 Cookie - searchterm}}",
                "search_term_previous": "{{Cookie - searchtermprevious}}",
                "search_term_all_lc": "{{Cookie - searchterm - Lowercase}}",
                "search_term_previous_all_lc": "{{Cookie - searchtermprevious - Lowercase}}",
                "is_user_logged_in_out": "{{MK - DL - user.status}}",
                "product_line_quantity": myCustomCartProducts[i].quantity,
                "product_line_price": myCustomCartProducts[i].price,
               
                items: [
                {
                "item_name": myCustomCartProducts[i].name ,
                "item_id": myCustomCartProducts[i].id ,
                "price": myCustomCartProducts[i].price,
                 "item_brand": myCustomCartProducts[i].brand,
                "item_category": myCustomCartProducts[i].category ,
                "quantity": myCustomCartProducts[i].quantity    

                }]
                    }); 
     
    
  
  }

When I change gtag to console.log the for loop completes normally.I am struggling to work out what is extending the length of the array/breaking the loop.

I suspect gtag is modifying the i variable. Always declare your variables as local, for (let i = ...)

Make the same fix in your gtag() function.

No need to even declare variables when you don't need them. Use a forEach() instead of that for. It's way more elegant and you don't need the awkward [i] everywhere. Plus, I don't think it's an infinite loop, you're likely just misinterpreting what's happening
